# MS Office applications not starting after opening and closing multiple times in Citrix environment

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-project, citrix

I have discovered some wierd issue I am having with the MS Office 365 applications in our firm. After opening and closing Project or Word more than 5 times, the application doesn't open anymore. If at this point the user tries to open program it just creats a background task.

This was discovered after some months of working on the version 2208 of Office 365. For this reason, I have downgraded to the version 2206, where the problem doesn't exist. Due to the discovered Zero-Day-Vulnerability of Outlook, I wanted to upgrade to the version 2303, but there seems to persist this problem.

After searching for the problem I have seen that either noone has discovered this issue or it is only happening to me.

The configuration of the PCs looks like this:

- Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise V2303 Build 16.0.16130.20306
- Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 1809 Build 17763.2928
- 16GB RAM
- Citrix Environment with V2203

The policies regarding the configuration of Office365 were the following:
[Network path to the storage of Office365 activation licenses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKf3b.png)
[Customization of Office in the registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Kzp.png)

If someone could help me out, that would be great.

**EDIT:** The problem of not opening persists only in the MS Project application. But there are still background processes running in the background of Word, Powerpoint and Publish, but somehow these applications still open. If the background processes are still there after normally closing the program, it is not possible to kill them with the task manager. The only solution is to restart the PC (for me).

**EDIT 2**: Unfortunately there are no error logs in the event viewer and I am not receiving any error messages from msproject.

Comment: How many times is "multiple times"?

Comment: After lets say 5 times opening and closing, but I have to check that again.

Comment: So if I were to open and close Word 5 times, I should be able to reproduce the issue?  I currently have 2202 installed.  Do I end the task or close it normally?

Comment: I have seen that Word still opens even if the background tasks are still there, but MS Project doesn't open anymore if there are unfinished processes there.

Comment: So I opened and closed word 10 times, I could not reproduce the issue with 2302, which suggests the issue might surround the Citrix environment itself.

Comment: @Ramhound Which windows version do you have installed?

Comment: The current version: W1022H2

Comment: It seems you are saying that Word opens OK but not Project. Is that correct? How about Access? Excel? PowerPoint? Outlook? Can you open Project in safe mode?

Comment: Is there any error message? Besides, is there any Ctrix policy applied to your environment?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon: The background processes also get generated when I try the same with powerpoint, excel and also publisher. With the other applications I couldnt reacreate the error.

Comment: @Emily: There appear no error messages in the event viewer. Have also searched for some specific policy, but the only policies were not citrix specific (attached in the post)